# Node and Webform - Open, Close, Scheduled and Limit per source entity

Tags: 8, webforms

I use Drupal 8 with webform. I have a content type called "Event" which has several fields of simple type and reference type for other content types.

In addition it has a field entity reference that points to a webform named "Team".

In "Event" in creation and edit mode, using the field_permissions-8.x-1.0-rc2 module, I prevent access to authenticated users,
because the default aspect is too complex for users who create content with the "Event" content type.

Among other things, if I do not prevent these settings, there is the possibility of changing the content type, which I would definitely not want.

For this reason I would like to link some simple fields of the "Event" content type to the "Team" webform.

- Status (open, closed, scheduled)
- Open (date and time)
- Closed (date and time)
- Max submissions (Total submissions limit per source entity)

Can anyone suggest me how to do it?
Can it be done with Tokens?
Should you use a Hook?
I searched the net but I didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Webform module includes the 'Webform Demo: Event Registration System' module which shows how to pass field related tokens from a Webform 'event' node to a webform submission.

Comment: Hi jrockowitz you are the best!!! Thankyou for your awesome work, webform is fantastic!!!

Comment: in the example there is the entity_limit_total handler but I don't find open close and scheduled with the relative date / time fields for opening and closing

Comment: maybe i can add my custom key, for example close_form, and related token?

Comment: ok maybe I anderstand, the key is in the YAML configuration?
For example If i want manage the status i need the kes "status" (open, closed, scheduled)

Comment: i try with handler key: token "status: [webform_submission:node:field_status:value]" but i become a error when i try to save the handler "Unknown custom status setting(s)." so I answer myself: no!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I insist, I keep asking myself without finding an answer: why in the section 'admin/structure/webform/manage/demo_event_registration/handlers' add-handler->custom settings, I find 'entity_limit_total' and can't find 'status', 'open_date' and 'close_date'?